# ArcGIS Pro 3D Scene Camera Settings

Tags: 3d, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to use ArcGIS Pro 2.0 to create photorealistic scenes from specific viewpoints. I often do wide panoramic views that require multiple photo exports that I put into photoshop and stitch together. In order to stitch them together accurately, the pitch should be consistent (ideally set to 0) and there should be some overlap. I also like to give a total bearing for the final photo in the report.

However, I can't find the camera parameters anywhere in an ArcGIS Pro Scene. I can select an imported viewpoint and zoom to it, set my elevation above ground, and pan around w/out moving location (hold down b). But I need to know what my pitch is, my bearing, field of view, etc. In the Animation Properties you can see these parameters for specific keyframes...so it must be possible to see somewhere w/out making an animation.

Comment: You have tags for ArcGIS Pro 1.x and 2.0 but what precise version are you using?  Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.

Comment: Fixed. I am using sing 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Go to View -> Navigation -> Camera.

This contains the heading, roll, pitch as well as X Y Z coordinates that you can set.